# Privacy error after Wordpress site migration to local server

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I'm still wondering for possible solution to this.

So I tried normal migration procedure for websites.

Copied the entire PHP script into my local server.
Replicated MariaDB database to my local server as well.
Now this thing happened next:

[image]

I've searched in the internet for others who encountered the same.

Anyway, the original site is hosted with SSL enabled.

Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/your-connection-is-not-private-warning-preventing-me-from-logging-in-on-my-wp-ad) link maybe helpful for you

Comment: Click `Advanced` link in the page you are showing. In the extended content Click `Proceed Anyway` to view your admin login for now.

Comment: @Gunaseelan Already looked into that, and there's no **Proceed Anyway** button. It says, _"You cannot visit beta.testserver.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later."_

Comment: @Gunaseelan: _"This link maybe helpful for you"_ --> Sorry mate, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your wordpress database look for `siteurl` and `home` inside `wp_options` table, change `https:` to `http:`

Or

Configured SSL on your local server.